# Add 5th keyboard layout on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I need to use 5 keyboard layouts, but I can add only 4 through preferences-> keyboard. After that the button 'Add' is inactive. Is there a way to add one more language?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

UPD: 
I tried the solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/107945/cant-add-more-than-four-keyboard-layouts, but it does not work for me because it is only for unity. I have xfce.

Comment: This script seems to work : http://askubuntu.com/a/66562/639270 According to askubuntu users. More details on this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/107945/cant-add-more-than-four-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 0):

The `XKB` system has a hard-coded limit of 4.  If you're using 5 different physical keyboards, you may be able to set a separate layout for each with separate `InputClass` configurations in `xorg.conf` (or snippets in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`).

If you're trying to use 5 layouts on 1 keyboard, you're probably out of luck until XKBv2.  See [XKB bug#19501](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19501) and [libxkbcommon issue#37](https://github.com/xkbcommon/libxkbcommon/issues/37).

You can script around the problem with a similar solution to [@NanoP's link](https://askubuntu.com/a/107948) -- that's a GNOME solution so it uses `gconftool-2` to load layout sets into the gconf registry, but a similar solution could be scripted with `setxkbmap`.

---

Depending on your specific use case, you may be interested in attempting to combine some of your layouts into customized versions that will fill your requirements while staying within the current limits.  For example, you could start with a basic `us` layout and add a `dvorak` or other layout on higher levels in the same layout (since basic `us` is pretty empty on ISO level 3 and higher).

Some resources:

- http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/
- https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450
- https://github.com/jbriales/xkb-extended-keys
- http://michal.kosmulski.org/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html
- http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php/Building_an_XKB_Keyboard
- https://gist.github.com/raphiz/f48f7062f6ff51cdc34d629bc24063cc
- https://github.com/mattventura/custom-xkb

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to change the gnome script over the weekend.